# Select distinct columns sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct, distinct-values

I have a table which contain `identity primary key id`, `CNum`, `CUID` and some other columns. I want to select distinct records based on `CNum` and `CUID`, in other words if two records have the same `CNum` and `CUID` I want to get the top one, I tried to group by but it will not work since the want the whole row.

```
with a as (SELECT distinct CNum, CUID
FROM Con) 
select c.CNum from Con c inner join
a on a.CNum = c.CNum
and a.CUID= c.CUID
order by id
```

This approach still gets duplicate records.

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Comment: What do you mean with "I tried group by group by but it will not work since the want the whole row"? Are you showing the whole query you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select the first row of a set of rows with the same characteristics, you can use the [ROW_NUMBER() function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) and PARTITION BY clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CNum, CUID ORDER BY Id) AS ROWNUM 
    FROM Con
) x WHERE x.ROWNUM = 1
```

The subquery adds a row number to each row having the same values for CNum/CUID.

Answer (score 0):

You missing `distinct` from final select statement

```
select distinct  c.CNum 
from Con c 
     inner join a on a.CNum = c.CNum and a.CUID= c.CUID
order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am mistaking, but I don't think you should include `from Con c` in your query.

You already included `Con` in the CTE, getting the distinct values there. If you use it here again, there is no point for your CTE.